# What's the integral of $\frac{-4x}{1+2x}$?

Tags: calculus, integration, ordinary-differential-equations

> Calculate the following: $$\int \frac{-4x}{1+2x}\ dx$$

I got $-1-2x+\ln(1+2x)$ as a result. But why does the answer say it is just $-2x+\ln(1+2x)$? Where did the $-1$ go?

Thank you

Comment: Constants don't matter when doing integrals. In this case, the $-1$ gets absorbed into the $+C$ that you should have put when doing the integral.

Answer (score 2):

You can check th ersult by computing the derivative of $-2x+\ln(1+2x)$. It is the same as that of $-1-2x+\ln(1+2x)$. In general, if $F$ is an antiderivative of $f$ then so is $F+c$ for any constant $c$.

Answer (score 1):

As $$\frac{-4x}{1+2x}=\frac{-2(1+2x)+2}{1+2x}=-2+\frac2{2x+1},$$

$$\int\frac{-4x}{1+2x}dx=-2\int dx+\int\frac2{1+2x}dx=-2x+\ln|1+2x|+C$$

putting $1+2x=u$ in the second integral
and where $C$ is an arbitrary constant of indefinite integral

In your case $C=-1$

In fact, if $$f'(x)=g'(x)\iff \int df(x)=\int d g(x)\implies f(x)=g(x)+K$$ where $K$ is an arbitrary constant of indefinite integral

Answer (score 0):

$$
\int\frac{-4x}{2x+1}dx=-4\int\frac{x}{2x+1}dx=-4\int\frac{\frac{2x+1}{2}-\frac{1}{2}}{2x+1}dx=-4\int\frac{\frac{1}{2}(2x+1-1)}{2x+1}dx=-2\int\frac{2x+1-1}{2x+1}dx=-2\int(\frac{2x+1}{2x+1}-\frac{1}{2x+1})dx=-2\int{(1-\frac{1}{2x+1})}dx=-2\int dx+2\int\frac{1}{2x+1}dx=-2x+\ln|2x+1|+C.
$$

$C$ is a integrabile constant which can be any real number, e.g. in your case $C=-1$, but the derivate of any constant is 0, i.e $C'=0$ for all $C\in\mathbb{R}$

Answer (score 0):

Let $u=1+2x$ then $du=2dx$ and $2-2u=-4x$.  Making the substitution
\begin{align}\int\frac{-4x}{1+2x}dx&=\int\frac{2-2u}{u}\frac{du}2\\&=\int\left(\frac1u-1\right)du\\&=\ln|u|-u+C\end{align}
Substituting back we have:
\begin{align}\int\frac{-4x}{1+2x}dx&=\ln|1+2x|-(1+2x)+C\\&=-2x+\ln|1+2x|+C-1\end{align}
Now, given that $C$ is a constant, any constant, so $C-1$ is also a constant.  Any constant.  So you can just drop it and have:
$$\int\frac{-4x}{1+2x}dx=-2x+\ln|1+2x|+K$$
The $-1$ is therefor unimportant.